# How to find the multi variable limit

Tags: calculus

Here is the multi variable function:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2-2|x|-2|y|}{|x|+|y|}$$

I have no idea to solve the limit

Comment: First I'd note that since the variables are all either squared or in absolute value, you can treat this as a one sided limit problem with only $x>0,y>0$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since all variables return non-negative results, you can assume $x,y>0$.

Rewriting limit: $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{x+y} - 2$

Then using polar coordinates $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$ as $r\to 0$, we get limit is $-2$

Comment: Polar coordinates do not provide the existence of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the Squeeze theorem as follows:
$$\color{red}{-2} \le \frac{x^2}{|x|+|y|} - 2 \le \frac{|x|^2}{|x|} -2 = \color{red}{|x| - 2}$$